# How do i get image using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jcrop

I am using jcrop to crop the image in my php application.I am using below code to pass the coordinate values and image path using ajax,

> ```
> function checkCoords(index)
>     {
>             if (parseInt(jQuery('#w').val())){
>                     jQuery.ajax({
>                         type    : "POST",
>                         cache: false,
>                         dataType: 'html',
>                         data    : {
>                                 x : jQuery('#x').val(),
>                                 y : jQuery('#y').val(),
>                                 w : jQuery('#w').val(),
>                                 h : jQuery('#h').val(),
>                        image_path : jQuery('#jc-hidden-image'+index).attr('src')
>                         },
>                         url     : BASE_URL+'apps/configure/cropimage',
>                         success : function(response) { 
>                                 jQuery(".preview_crop").html(response);
>                         }
>                     });                     
>             } 
>             else{
>                 alert('Please select a crop region then press Crop button.');
>             }
> ```

In Controller, I use the ajax value as below,

```
  public function cropimageAction(){
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        //d($params);
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
        {
                $targ_w = $targ_h = 150;
                $jpeg_quality = 90;

                $src = $params['image_path'];
                $img_r = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
                $dst_r = ImageCreateTrueColor( $targ_w, $targ_h );

                $image  = imagecopyresampled($dst_r,$img_r,0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);

               header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);

                exit;
        }        
    }
```

I got the response as something like

> ��(��(��(��(��

Instead of cropped image, got some symbol. Need to get cropped image in ajax response. What i done wrong on this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are sending the full image data back as response, instead save the image on the server and send the URL to it as a response

instead

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($dst_r,null,$jpeg_quality);
```

have this

```
imagejpeg($dst_r,"path/where/to/save/image.jpg",$jpeg_quality);
echo "path/where/to/save/image.jpg";
```

Also, your success function should look like

```
success : function(url) { 
    jQuery(".preview_crop").html('<img src="' + url + '" />');
}
```